# Can't get Angular-ui ui.route to route along with Apache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, angular-ui-router

I'm running my web app on my pc, via an Apache server.
For some reason, my routing provided by ui.route never gets the one simple state I defined, and it's being a real pain.

To debug it, I threw in a wildcard to catch all paths, and discovered that the path ui.routing keeps getting is: "" .

Why is it?

Here's my app.js:

```
angular.module('populaApp', [
  'populaApp.controllers','ui.bootstrap','ngEmbedApp','ui.router',
]).config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
            url: "*path",
      templateUrl: "http://localhost/popula/app/html/tagsview.html",
            controller: "listsController"
    });
});
```

and my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

on my controller, I wrote:

```
console.log($stateParams);
```

and it echoed:

```
Object {path: ""}
```

no matter what the path really is.

Any advice?

Comment: did you enable `html5mode` ?

Comment: nope, should I?
P.S. I got the <base href="/"></base> set in index.html

Comment: yep, because by default angular will match urls with `#` as prefix. i.e  `#home/other/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable [html5Mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

so, in your config

```
angular.module('populaApp', [
  'populaApp.controllers','ui.bootstrap','ngEmbedApp','ui.router',
]).config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
            url: "*path",
      templateUrl: "http://localhost/popula/app/html/tagsview.html",
            controller: "listsController"
    });
});
```

Why? If you don't enable `html5mode`,  by default angular will match only urls with `#` as prefix. i.e `myserver.com/#home` .

Comment: @ShayMazor no problem :)  I see you are a new users, so, you can mark as correct answer by clicking over the check.